# Cannot pass variable for DB operations in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.5, pymysql

I have this in my main.py:

```
# Find negatif score of a word
analysis.sentiword_negscore("unable")
db_operations.connection_close()
```

This one in analysis.py:

```
# Find the sentiword point of a word
def sentiword_negscore(word):
    negscore = db_operations.find_negscore(word)
    print(word + "has negatif score of: " + negscore)
```

This one in db_operations.py:

```
def find_negscore(word):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `neg_score` FROM `allwords` WHERE `synset_terms_en`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (word))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        return result

def connection_close():
    connection.close()
```

When I run my main.py, then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    analysis.sentiword_negscore("unable")
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/bin/application/analysis.py", line 49, in sentiword_negscore
    negscore = db_operations.find_negscore(word)
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/bin/application/db_operations.py", line 31, in find_negscore
    cursor.execute(sql, (word))
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 167, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 323, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 835, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/Users/efe/virtualenvs/virt1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1034, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

What could be wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It must be tuple:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (word, )) # instead of cursor.execute(sql, (word))
```